# How to stop losing request parameters in expressjs?

Tags: express

I have defined my route in a separate `route.js` file as below (details removed for brevity)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.route('')put(function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params.id); //prints undefined
});
```

and in `server.js` I map this route as below

```
var route = require('./routes/route.js');
app.use('/api/use/:id/role', route);
```

My route function is correctly invoked but the `id` parameter is not available in the router handler. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`mergeParams`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) option:

```
var router = express.Router({ mergeParams : true });
```

Full standalone example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = app.listen(3000);
var router  = express.Router({ mergeParams : true });

router.route('').get(function(req, res) {
  console.log('id', req.params.id);
  return res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.use('/api/use/:id/role', router);
```

Comment: Adding it to child router does not work. `req.params` is still empty.

Comment: @Suhas I posted a full example that works for me (using `express@4.13.3`)